# why does it exclude the minimum?

Tags: python-3.x, range

I was testing my program, and found out some bugs.
I was able to fix some of them by myself, but I need help on this.

Basically, there are three functions (word frequency, chapter counter, and verse counter). [I only posted the word frequency part of it] When I tested the first one which is word frequency, I noticed that the minimum book and chapters are not working. in other words, If I want to get word frequency from book of 49 chapter 6(which is the last chapter of 49) to book of 50 chapter 2, it excludes the book 49 chapter 6.

How should I fix it??

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import operator
import requests
import re
import bs4


def word_frequency(max_book_w, max_chapter_w):
    word_list = []
    book = b
    chapter = c
    while book <= max_book_w:
        while chapter <= max_chapter_w:
            url = 'http://www.holybible.or.kr/B_NIV/cgi/bibleftxt.php?VR=NIV&VL={}&CN={}&CV=99'.format(book, chapter)
            source_code = requests.get(url).text
            soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code, "html.parser")
            for bible_text in soup.findAll('font', {'class': 'tk4l'}):
                content = bible_text.get_text()
                words = content.lower().replace('-', ' ').split()
                for each_word in words:
                    word_list.append(each_word)
            chapter += 1
        book += 1
        chapter = 1
    clean_up_list(word_list)


def clean_up_list(word_list):
    clean_word_list = []
    for word in word_list:
        symbols = "~:!@#$%^&*()_+`{}|\"?><`-=\][';/.,']"
        for i in range(0, len(symbols)):
            word = word.replace(symbols[i], "")
        if len(word) > 0:
            clean_word_list.append(word)
    dictionary(clean_word_list)


def dictionary(clean_word_list):
    word_count = {}
    for word in clean_word_list:
        if word in word_count:
            word_count[word] += 1
        else:
            word_count[word] = 1
    for key, value in sorted(word_count.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)):
        print(key, value)

user = int(input('''What do you need a help on?
          1 - word frequency, 2 - chapter count, 3 - verse count'''))
    if user == 1:
        b = int(input("type the starting book"))
        c = int(input("type the starting chapter of the book"))
        x = max_book_w = int(input("type the last book"))
        y = max_chapter_w = int(input("what chapter of the book would be the last chapter?"))
        word_frequency(x, y)
    elif user == 2:
        min_b = int(input("what is the starting book?"))
        max_b = int(input("what is the last book?"))
        chapter_counter(max_b)
    elif user == 3:
        books = int(input("which book do you want?"))
        chapters = int(input("which chapter of the book you want?"))
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            verse(books, chapters)
```

1st edit: Actually, it is the first book not only the chapter that this program excludes. I tried with 49-5 to 50-2 but neither 49-5 nor 49-6 was included.

Comment: Take a look at [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I believe that it's possible to significantly reduce your code to something smaller with the same problem.

Comment: why aren't you passing `b`(the starting book), and `c`(the starting chapter of the book) to `word_frequency(x, y)`? Currently `word_frequency` is only receiving `max_book_w` and `max_chapter_w`..

Comment: I assigned book =b and chapter = c under def word_freq

Comment: ok, i'm not familiar enough with it to debug further